# ASP.NET WebForms - Issues disabling list item

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, .net-4.6

I am running (ASP.NET Web Forms) VB.Net code and in the aspx page, i have something like this:

```
<ul id="tabsdefault" class="tab-menu">
        <li id="accessingIndividuals" runat="server"><a>Accessing Individuals</a></li>
</ul>
```

and in the code behind file, i have this code:

```
accessingIndividuals.Disabled = true
```

However, before upgrading to .NET 4.6, this code worked and now after the upgrade, it does not disable the list item.

I have also manually changed the aspx page item with this:

```
<ul id="tabsdefault" class="tab-menu">
        <li id="accessingIndividuals" runat="server" disabled="disabled"><a>Accessing Individuals</a></li>
</ul>
```

but that did not work and nor did the following:

```
<ul id="tabsdefault" class="tab-menu">
        <li id="accessingIndividuals" runat="server" disabled="true"><a>Accessing Individuals</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any idea what has changed in .NET Framework or how can disable this item?

Looking at the page source using Developer Tools, the output is like this:

```
    <ul id="tabsdefault" class="tab-menu">
        <li id="accessingIndividuals" enabled="false" disabled="disabled" class="selected"><a>Accessing Individuals</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: When you say disabled, you mean you were not able to click on the listitem previously but now you are able to click on it even when it is marked as disable?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: Yes that is what i mean

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all new Browsers ignore the disable attribute on a list item. One possible solution is:

```
    li[disabled]
    {
      pointer-events: none;
      opacity: 0.6;
    }
```